# Android: Upload picture on Flickr

Tags: android, upload, flickr

I have to make an android app to upload a picture from mobile to Flickr.
I started reading [API Flickr Documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/), but still miss understanding how to autenticate and how to upload.
I also read similar questions here, but they show incomplete code snippet, so I can't test them.
Can anyone help me? Any link to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [flickrj](https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/) library. It's designed to work with Android. It comes with [source code](http://code.google.com/p/flickr-viewer-for-honeycomb/) to a sample app [available](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.charleszq) in the Google Play market.

Comment: Hey Gunnar, I am using this Flickr example code: http://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/source/browse/ using this I want to upload the photos from my application. But it is not allowed me to even upload,edit or replace the or even Delete the files. Can you please suggest me at where I am wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mpp. Sounds like you haven't done auth/login for your app, but impossible to tell without more data. Try to pinpoint the code that doesn't work for you and post it with error messages as a new question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

[Full Demo](https://github.com/luminousman/Flickr) application and working example...
For details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524440/1136023

Comment: anyway, can we get the url of that image in Flickr? I cannot see any lines of code of that task :(