# Upload image to Flickr and get URL of it

Tags: android, image, flickr

I want to send image message in my chat application so I'm planning to upload it to Flickr and get the static url from it, then I can send that url to other device (and save into the DB too).

I know the api of it is : https://up.flickr.com/services/upload/

But I dont know how to set parameter for it and save images also. Anyone have a solution for it?

This is my class about Upload Image Task:

```
public class UploadPhotoTask extends AsyncTask<OAuth, Void, String> {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private final FlickrjActivity flickrjAndroidSampleActivity;
    private File file;

    // private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
    // .getLogger(UploadPhotoTask.class);

    public UploadPhotoTask(FlickrjActivity flickrjAndroidSampleActivity,
            File file) {
        this.flickrjAndroidSampleActivity = flickrjAndroidSampleActivity;
        this.file = file;
    }

    /**
     * The progress dialog before going to the browser.
     */
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(flickrjAndroidSampleActivity,
                "", "Uploading..."); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dlg) {
                UploadPhotoTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(OAuth... params) {
        OAuth oauth = params[0];
        OAuthToken token = oauth.getToken();

        try {
            Flickr f = FlickrHelper.getInstance().getFlickrAuthed(
                    token.getOauthToken(), token.getOauthTokenSecret());

            UploadMetaData uploadMetaData = new UploadMetaData();
            uploadMetaData.setTitle("" + file.getName());
            return f.getUploader().upload(file.getName(),
                    new FileInputStream(file), uploadMetaData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("boom!!", "" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (response != null) {
            Log.e("", "" + response);
        } else {

        }

        if (monUploadDone != null) {
            monUploadDone.onComplete();
        }

        Toast.makeText(flickrjAndroidSampleActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    onUploadDone monUploadDone;

    public void setOnUploadDone(onUploadDone monUploadDone) {
        this.monUploadDone = monUploadDone;
    }

    public interface onUploadDone {
        void onComplete();
    }

}
```

Besides, how can we get URL of that images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [developer guide](https://www.flickr.com/services/developer/api/) for details on how to use the api and working examples.

Also there is [this existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565456/android-upload-picture-on-flickr) with similar query.

Try using the [flickrj library](https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/) as per that other post.

Comment: anyway, can we get the url of that image in Flickr? I cannot see any lines of code of that task :(